# Get TFS associated work item of a checkin (not changeset)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I am creating a server side code review policy for TFS and I currently have it working for any checkin that runs through visual studio, But when someone trys to checkin through the Web UI it doesnt work.

The policy is looking for an associated work item on the checkin and then looks through that work item to confirm it meets specific requirements. I am able to get the associated work item from visual studio check in's via

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(IVssRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            statusMessage = string.Empty;
            properties = new ExceptionPropertyCollection();

            var checkinNotification = notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification;
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.DecisionPoint && notificationEventArgs is CheckinNotification)
            {

                bool isNullComment = false;
                bool isCheckinContains = false;

                var service = requestContext.GetService<ILocationService>();

                TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(GetTfsUri(requestContext));

                WorkItemStore workitemStore = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

                var changes = checkinNotification.GetSubmittedItems(requestContext);

                isCheckinContains = changes.Any(change => change.ToUpper().Contains("$/"));
                if (isCheckinContains)
                {
                    isNullComment = string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkinNotification.Comment.ToString());

                    //Read all associated workitem id's 
                    var assoWorkItems = checkinNotification.NotificationInfo.WorkItemInfo.Select(x => x.Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

this however does not work with the web UI. The main difference I notice when running the code against Visual studio and the web UI is the request context refers to a very different URL.

Visual Studio Request context URL:  http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v5.0/repository.asmx

Web Ui request context: http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets

I believe I need to use a different namespace and methods to access the info inside the checkin using the web UI.

I have been trying to use the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi" namespace to get data from the web UI, but I cannot find any info online on how to get info of a checkin that is trying to process

Comment: What do you mean "*not a changeset*"? *Check in* is an action that a user performs that **creates** a changeset. There's no entity called a "check in" that you can retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

The web editing experience uses a different set of APIs, as you've observed. Server-side policies apparently don't get processed when using the newer APIs, as server-side plugins are a supported-but-not-really-recommended-heading-toward-being-deprecated type of feature.

So basically, your policy doesn't apply to the web UI, and there's no way to make it. You can suggest that Microsoft add support by posting something on UserVoice, but that's about it.